# Ionic compounds with hydride anion

Tags: bond, ionic-compounds, hydrides

Ionic compounds are formed when an atom $\ce{A}$ donates one of it's electron to another atom $\ce{B}$ to form an ionic compound $\ce{A+B-}$. This is significantly more likely to happen as the electronegativity difference of $\ce{A}$ and  $\ce{B}$ increases.

Hydrogen has a Pauling electronegativity of $2.20$. So, it appears to me that $\ce{H_2}$ should be able to form ionic bonds both as
$$\ce{H+ + A- -> H+A-}$$
$$\ce{B+ + H- -> B+H-}$$

What are compounds that contain $\ce{H-}$ called and what are some examples?

Comment: H+ can't form a true ionic bond. H- can and does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hydrogen does form ionic bonds. Although not as bare $\ce{H+}$, it can form ionic bonds in the form of $\ce{H-}$  ([hydride anion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_anion)). $\ce{H-}$ forms ionic bonds with alkali metal ions and alkaline earth metal ions (except $\ce{Be^{2+}}$).  These type of ionic compounds formed by hydride ion are called [saline hydrides](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Inorganic_Chemistry_(Housecroft)/10%3A_Hydrogen/10.7%3A_Binary_Hydrides_-_Classification_and_General_Properties/10.7C%3A_Saline_Hydrides), as they are salt type. These hydrides like $\ce{CaH2}$ (also known as hydrolith) can also be used for production of dihydrogen, as reducing agents, desiccant.